# Is it possible to initialize an object inside another object initialization without constructors?

Tags: typescript

What I need is fairly simple, I just want to initialize an object that is a child of another object which I am initializing. In C# it would look something like this:

```
var car = new Car { 
serialNumber = 25,
engine = new Engine {
    horsePower = 500
    }
}
```

In this example code I am initializing the Engine type inside the initialization of the Car type.
While trying to do this with TypeScript no matter what I try I get syntax errors.

Here is my TypeScript code:

```
var car: Car = new Car({
serialNumber: 25,
    engine: new Engine({ 
        horsePower: 500
    })
});
```

This block of code just does not work, and all the classes used in the code here are obviously imported.

Could it really be a basic feature like this isn't supported in TypeScript?

EDIT:
There is no constructor in these classes. Here's how they look:

```
export class Car { 
    serialNumber: number;
    engine: Engine;
}
```

Comment: If that piece of code is giving you errors, I would just suggest to initialize "Engine" before the initialization of Car and then use it on the Car class initialization ;)

Comment: @gascon95 This code is only for reference, In my code it is far more complicated, I have multiple objects to initialize and I find it time consuming and ineffective to initialize each object beforehand and create a variable. The solution is obviously easy, but the question is if that really is the only way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly do this, you just have to pass the correct constructor arguments.

The code you've written passes a single constructor argument object with keys. So your classes should look something like this:

```
class Car {
    constructor(args: { serialNumber: number; engine: Engine; }) { }
}

class Engine {
    constructor(args: { horsePower: number; }) { }
}
```

If, however, your classes use multiple named constructor arguments, like this:

```
class Car {
    constructor(serialNumber: number, engine: Engine) { }
}

class Engine {
    constructor(horsePower: number) { }
}
```

Then you simply have to pass your constructor arguments correctly:

```
const car: Car = new Car(25, new Engine(500));
```

**EDIT**

> that would require me to create a constructor which is kind of annoying

I'm a bit confused... your original code uses classes, so you should already have a constructor unless you are adding each property using an assignment. **Please post a complete example.**

If you're just trying to create a nested object literal structure, you just need an interface, then create the object using normal JS object literal notation:

```
interface Car {
  serialNumber: number;
  engine: Engine;
}

interface Engine {
  horsePower: number;
}

const car: Car = {
  serialNumber: 25,
  engine: { 
    horsePower: 500
  }
};
```

If you're trying to assign an object literal to a class type, then you're doing it wrong. :)

**EDIT 2**

So, you have a class with properties and no constructor. This means you can't instantiate it with properties, either nested or one at a time. You *could* write a generic helper function to instantiate a class and assign properties:

```
function create<T>(constructor: new() => T, props: Partial<T>): T {
    let instance = new constructor();
    for (let key in props) {
        instance[key] = props[key];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

And then create a nested class object like this:

```
const car = create(Car, {
    serialNumber: 123,
    engine: create(Engine, {
        horsePower: 456
    })
});
```

But if your classes really just have properties, I think you'd be better off just using interfaces and object literals (as in my previous example).

Comment: I added an example code of the class, And i'll try using interface and see what happens.

Comment: Ok. I see your class has properties but no constructor. This means you can't instantiate it with properties, either nested or one at a time. Is your question really "how do I initialize a class instance with properties without using a constructor?"

Comment: Yeah I guess so, sorry for misleading. Also I found something else that is dumb, if i have a constructor without parameters and initialize the object the constructor code won't fire. The more i use typescript the more I hate it :/

Comment: `if i have a constructor without parameters and initialize the object the constructor code won't fire` -- [that's *definitely* not true](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(%22hello%22)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Foo()%3B), something else must be wrong with your code.

Comment: It sounds retarded but I'm telling you, that's how it is. After adding a useless parameter just to verify the constructor code works.

Comment: I don't believe it. :) You probably aren't aren't calling the constructor. But I 'd have to see your code. So do you still have an open question here?

Comment: Awesome Aaron, this works great, though i can instantiate an object like that one at a time without this code, but with this it will work nested as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is definitely you can. But you syntax has a probelm.

```
var car = new Car(
       serialNumber: 25,
      engine: new Engine{ 
      horsePower: 500
     }
 );
```

and the Car class should be like this:

```
public class Car(int serialNumber, Engine engine) {

 .....
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting the same error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: As I said, you Car class structure should look like above. What is the Car class structure?

Comment: I modified the post, I made a mistake in writing that.

Comment: It makes no difference and i don't see how it would've made a difference.

Comment: As I said, there is an issue with class constructor. The class could simply have no constructors. Check that. You may copy it here.

Comment: Oh OK, I understand what you did. It would solve the problem but that would require me to create a constructor which is kind of annoying. I just wanted to find out if there is a way to do this without a constructor.